לממשׁלת Psalm 136:8,9 and Gen 1:16 could it be meaning "for him to govern from?"
I've been working my way through every Hebrew word in psalms and proverbs, learning as I go and putting it in my own words. I've just finished Psalm 136 and thought I would ask about the words לממשׁלת in v8 and לממשׁלות in v9.
I deconstruct each word into its suffixes, root and prefixes like this: ל=for מ=from  משׁל=mashal to rule or govern ות and ת=him and then translated Ps 136:7-9 as:
7 For He made great lights, For His mercy is forever.
8 The sun for him to govern from by day, For His mercy is forever.
9 The moon and stars for him to govern from by night, For His mercy is forever.
לממשׁלות is used exclusively in Psalm 136:9 and in v8 לממשׁלת is used only here and twice in Genesis 1:16 and directly refers to that moment in creation.
Could it be meaning that God himself is governing from the sun, moon and stars, rather than the sun moon and stars governing?

Please clarify "it" in context with what you want to know here. Even include links to show the Hebrew word or words in a setting of an interlinear context for anyone not steeped in reading/understanding Hebrew.
